# Homotopically trivial path in $S^1$ is homotopically trivial relative ends?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Having a path $\alpha:[0,1]\rightarrow S^1$ satisfying $\alpha(0)=\alpha(1)=1,$ which is homotopic to the constant map $\beta(t) \equiv 1,$ is it true that it is homotopic with fixed ends to the constant map as well?

Comment: No. Consider $t \mapsto e^{2\pi it}$, then $f_{s} (t) = e^{2\pi i s t}$ is a homotopy (without fixed ends) between $f_{1}$ and the constant map.

Comment: Yes, sorry that was trivial actually. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not true, let $\mathbb{S}^1 := \{z \in \mathbb{C}\:|\:|z| = 1\}$ and $I = [0,1]$.

Take
$$\alpha : I \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$$
$$s \mapsto e^{i2\pi s}$$
and consider the following homotopy:
$$H : I \times I \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1 $$

$$(s,t) \mapsto e^{i2\pi s(1 - t)}$$
Then $H$ is an homotopy between $\alpha$ and $\varepsilon_1$ (constant path at $1$),but it is well known that $\alpha$ is not homotopically equivalent to $\varepsilon_1$ relative to $\partial I = \{0,1\}$

Edit: I see know that my counterexample is the same as Tom Ariel’s comment

Answer (score 3):

For any topological space $X$, any path $\gamma:[0, 1]\to X$ is homotopic to the constant map $t\mapsto \gamma(0)$. A homotopy $H:[0, 1]\times[0, 1]\to X$ may be defined as $H(t, s) = \gamma(ts)$.

With this in mind (i.e. that being homotopic to $\beta$ is a trivial and superfluous condition), it shouldn't be difficult to find counterexample $\alpha$'s that are not endpoint-fixed-homotopic to $\beta$.